# lilbreoffice writer: How to change underline to bold?

Tags: replace, attributes, libreoffice-writer

Sir:

I use libreoffice writer and am wondering if it is possible to change all italic to bold?

> There are **bird**, **dog** and **carrot**.

to

> There are *bird*, *dog* and *carrot*.

in a markup language rule, change all [B]text[/B] to [I]text[/I] throughout the document.

I also want to change other attributes (super/subscript). Editing rich text file is not as easy as I thought.

Does anybody know how?

thank you in advance

Comment: Note to whoever voted to close: I understand the reasoning for suggesting superuser.com instead, and indeed, my answer does not involve programming. However, an answer *could potentially* have involved programming, and how would the OP know before an answer has been posted? So perhaps it's acceptable to post such a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [AltSearch](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer), select to search for *Bold* from the Properties menu. In the replacement, specify `\A{CharPosture=2}\A{CharWeight=0}`, either by typing that in or by selecting those properties after pressing Pick Properties.

It is possible to do this without AltSearch by using normal Search & Replace to find the attributes and then selecting all results. Then close the dialog and manually change the formatting, which will apply to all selections (hopefully there aren't too many or it may be slow!). Detailed steps are at https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-do-i-replace-underlined-text-with-italics/45195/2.

It may also be worth using character styles instead of direct formatting so that you can instantly change to a different type of formatting instead of requiring search and replace. For bold and italics alone it may not be worth it, but it sounds like your document may have more complexity than that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now, I know how to. I have been spending time with libreoffice scripting and SDK. (totally off track!)